# How to reliably identify referrer on client browser?

Tags: web-browser, http, client-side, header, client

Is there any way to reliably identify the referring site on modern browsers (not considering manual HTTP requests outside of a browser e.g. cURL, etc.)?

Referrer header will not work because the referring site could just set `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer`.

Is there anything else that exists that will be there 100% of the time on the client browser that includes at least the origin? It seems like a valid use case to make sure you know where the traffic is coming from to your site (without a way for the site sending you traffic to hide themselves)?

Answer (score 1):

There is now way to do that.

Your view is:

> It seems like a valid use case to make sure you know where the traffic is coming from.

But there is another view. Many users want to keep their privacy. It is also a valid use case. See the [Referrer Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#intro-privacy) that the major browsers follow:

> The social networking site might not wish to leak the user’s profile URL to the band web sites when other users follow those hyperlinks (because the profile URLs might reveal the identity of the owner of the profile).

Besides, URLs can contains user's session ID. Disclosing it to the other site would mean a security risk. Another risk in such case: When the target site uses HTTP, then the traffic can be intercepted and also other parties can obtain session ID.

That's why the referrer policy is very important and the major browsers follow it.

If the web site defines particular policy and if the browser respects it, then for the target web site there is no way to know where the traffic is coming from.